# Retrieve list of account entity names from Dynamics CRM (Online) using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, extract, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I wanted to know if it is possible to retrieve a list of all account names using PowerShell?
Basically if you run the following URL in your browser https://OrgURL/api/data/v9.2/accounts?$select=name  you will get the below result:

[image]

Is it possible to get a similar result in PowerShell with the Display names of the account records?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7.2).

Comment: Currently the problem appears to be authorization. Currently if you try loading the URL https://YourOrg.crm4.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.2/accounts?$select=name directly into the browser you will get 401.
If you want the data to be displayed (as per the initial screenshot) you first need to login into Dynamics and load the URL in a separate tab.

Comment: The problem with PowerShell is even if I try to pass credentials when trying to Invoke https://YourOrg.crm4.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.2/accounts?$select=name I get "Invoke-WebRequest : The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized", because this URL, by default, does not require authentication.

Comment: what authentication option does `YourOrg.crm4.dynamics.com` offer? Cookies, Token, basic, etc.? You need to adjust the code with the correct authentication.

Comment: I have added a sample to the original post

Comment: Does it work (if yes, you could add it as answer) or do you need some further help?

Comment: Unfortunately it does not, and I cannot find my error at this point. It is also possible that this cannot be achieved, but I ama not certain at this point

Answer (score 0):

In order to connect to a Dynamics 365/Dataverse instance using PowerShell, you have two options:

1. Invoke-WebRequest as the other answer (but you need to provide at least the bearer token in order to authenticate the requests)
2. this cmdlet: Microsoft.Xrm.Data.PowerShell https://github.com/seanmcne/Microsoft.Xrm.Data.PowerShell

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue - the application account did not have the rights to view acc records.